# Was punch card "correction tape" for real?

Tags: fortran

I learned FORTRAN the old fashioned way, sitting at a card punch console. I was once offered the use of some punch card "correction tape" that appeared to be the correct width to cover one column of the card.

I declined the offer of "candy from a stranger" but later wondered if it was for real, or just a gag.

---

It's sobering to see there are no tags here for punch-card or [punched card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) or even Hollerith!

Comment: @O.Jones actually it looks like they don't, your tag seems to have been "corrected" :-(

Comment: folks reading this post may also be able to add an answer to the Retrocomputing SE question [What did a "blue-and-gray sheet of IBM printout paper" actually look like, circa 1994?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28043/7118)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that stuff. Thin opaque Mylar.

I tried to use it once or twice, but it was always easier to remake the card.

Bad old days.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having myself (year : 1979) covered wrong holes with a piece of tape and drilled right holes with a spike of compass, just because my office was far from the card punch console.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember using correction tape, but do remember hand punches where you had to manually press two or more keys for a single alpha character or punctuation mark. I also remember working with decks of cards containing binary machine codes - you wouldn't want to use correction tape with those.